# pass the result of command to another in batches

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, shell, pip

Lets say command1 results an array of 10000 value,

I want to pass this result to command2 in 20 patches, 500 value each.

What I have now

```
command1 arg $(command2 arg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xargs` for this purpose:

```
command2 arg | xargs -n 500 command1
```

`xargs` is a program to build and execute command lines from standard input
.

- `-n` says each time run the `command` with 500 input given from `stdin`.

To test it:

```
$ echo `for i in {1..50}; do echo $i; done;` | xargs -n 10 echo

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

Comment: That's great, I accepted the answer, Can I make the Command 1 arguments dynamic also? changing with each patch?

Comment: let say command1 is addToFile filename , can I male the filename changes for each patch?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve you want some time run the command with parameter A and sometimes B?

Comment: okay, Command1 creates a file given a filename and array of values, command2 result is 10000 values, I want to have 20 files with different names each having 500 values. What I achieved with your help was writing to the same file 20 times, I want to make the result separated to 20 files

Comment: Please note that I am using the file creation command as an example.

Comment: unfortunately I think that's not possible, however have a look at `man xargs` and `-p` option it might help you.